# Naming website strings

Tags: naming

There are 2 types of strings in any website:

1. Shorter with no formatting (menu items, section titles, labels...).
2. Longer with formatting (content).

If you have to store these 2 types of strings in 2 different database tables, how would you call these 2 tables?

Comment: What do you mean by no/formatting? If you are referring to escaping, I think it is wiser to escape all the textual data before displaying them or before storing them in the DB, unless you have a very good reason for not doing so. You might have a short string that's `M and M` today and later it might be necessary to change it to `M & M`.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the advice! I'll have it in mind.

Comment: Why are you putting such different types of data into the same field (or even the same table)? Why not have different tables for pages, menus, sections, and labels?

Comment: Because I don't find them to be that different. Why use multiple tables when you can use one? What's the benefit in this case?

Comment: The benefit is modularity and, by extension, maintainability. Sure, you could put them all in the same field, just as you could use `TEXT` or `BLOB` fields to store all of your data, but that is a poor practice. You lose semantic structure and that limits what you can do with the data. It's also inefficient to have to sort through a bunch of menu items and section titles when you only want to look up a label. I mean, you could theoretically store all of that data in a single field of a single record as well, but that is not a sane database design.

Comment: I'd also point out that properly modeling your data is critical to good application design. Spending a little extra time to model your data correctly early on will save you a lot of headaches latter on. Even if you see no advantage in properly structuring or normalizing your database right now because it's just a simple app, there's always the possibility that you might want to add features or extend the application in the future. You don't want to shoot yourself in the foot. And the fact you're having a hard time naming the field should be a hint that your database design is dubious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Labels
2. Content

Comment: I like "labels". It might be the best so far. Content is too broad I think, plus I need something in plural. Maybe I'll use "texts" for the second one.

Comment: Content is a common word for this type. Maybe PageContent or SiteContent might sound more suitable. But, in my opinion, Content covers all related fileds you told, and apparent enough for people who see the mane and try to guess what it might be store.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL the shorter ones are generally called `varchar` and the longer ones `text`.

That's not to say that you'd never put HTML in a `varchar`, just that `text` fields are better suited for arbitrary-length strings.

Comment: Sure, I'd definitely use the "varchar" data type for type 1 and the "text" for type 2. What I'm looking for the names of the 2 tables that would store these 2 types of strings.

Comment: Why not call one strings and one text?

Comment: @Skilldrick: That's been exactly what I've been planing on calling them. Just wanted to see some opinions before I make my decision.

Comment: @Skilldrick: The problem I have with "strings" and "texts" is that a text is basically a string so that's it.

Comment: I think as long as you're consistent in your naming it'll be fairly obvious what you mean. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Localization strings?
2. Content

In short, call the tables after their content.

If you have both application texts, content titles and content you might use three tables, "ApplicationTexts", "ContentTitles", "Content".

Comment: The thing is that the 2nd table also contains localization strings so this wouldn't really work form me.